# Microsoft Teams React App prevent style overwriting from SharePoint Online

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, microsoft-teams, fluentui-react

I have developed a Microsoft Teams App with some Fluent UI React components.
The app is deployed on the SharePoint App catalog and added with the app manifest to MS Teams.
In MS Teams I want to use the default styles of the client.

The issue is that the App is using the SharePoint Online custom design of the Tenant.
How can I prevent this behavior?

Cheers and Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you used the SharePoint Framework. You need to check the context in your app:

```
  if (this.context.sdks.microsoftTeams) {
    // We have Teams context

  }
  else
  {
    // We are in SharePoint context

  }
```

Once you know you are in Teams, you can grab and use the context theme `context.sdks.microsoftTeams.context.theme`